# MySQL table/row/cell data compare tool ? A la winmerge?

Tags: mysql, compare, winmerge

is there any such tool to compare row data and cell data between two mysql tables ?
Say you have 2 different cells (values) in a row (same row idenfied by primary key) and you want to "Copy to Left" from one cell to the other, skip the next difference, and again Copy to Left (so not syncronize aka copy all).
The compare part i saw present in Toad for mysql, but not the "edit" part (a la winmerge), on a per cell (or row) basis.

Does anything like this even exist?

Answer (score 0):

Well, we can offer our [dbForge Data Compare for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/datacompare/), which has such functionality. You'll need to check necessary rows manually, like this:

[image: dbForge Data Compare for MySQL]